# Почему зависает Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

Зависает Убунту. При этом на экране как стоп-кадр. Звук пропадает через 5 секунд. Изображение остаётся пока не нажму Reset

```
Nov  5 15:54:12 victor-OptiPlex-790 kernel: 
    [24884.238009] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
Nov  5 15:54:12 victor-OptiPlex-790 kernel: 
    [24884.238027] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Nov  5 15:54:12 victor-OptiPlex-790 kernel: 
    [24884.238041] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 6: killed
Nov  5 15:54:12 victor-OptiPlex-790 kernel: 
    [24884.238051] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Nov  5 15:54:12 victor-OptiPlex-790 kernel: 
    [24884.238846] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: chrome[3263]: channel 6 killed!
```

Comment: два варианта - либо хром не дружит с nouveau, либо просто мало памяти (в это верю).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку гуглил? Пробовал [этот метод](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897627/ubuntu-showing-sched-error-20-on-boot)?

Было подобное с debian-based дистрибутивами, где-то в июне-июле этого года. После обновления при прослушивании музыки/просмотре фильмов система зависала намертво. Решил проблему откатом на более старую версию.
Сейчас перешёл на elementary, в ней возникла подобная проблема - решил её установив последнюю версию проприетарных дров от NVIDIA.

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка видео драйвера *Nouveau*. Для деталей, проверьте [bugs.freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=nv50cal_space&list_id=663471&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&query_format=specific), особенно: [#93629](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93629), [#99900](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99900) and [#100567](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100567) (которые связаны с `SCHED_ERROR`/`CTXSW_TIMEOUT`).

Для отладки заморозки вы можете использовать [Magic SysRq key](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SysRq), например:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> - позволяет менять уровень подробности вывода.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> - выдаст список всех непрерываемых задач.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> - Показывает трассировку стека для всех активных процессоров.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> - Oвыдаст список текущих задач и информацию о них в текущую консоль.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> - Вывести текущие регистры и флаги на консоль.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> - Показать все активные таймеры высокого разрешения и источники часов.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> - выдаст информацию о доступной и занятой оперативной памяти.

Предлагаемые решения:

- Обновите Ubuntu и ядро до последней версии.
- Если проблема повторяется, обходной путь должен установить [драйверы NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/78223), который заменяет видео драйвер Nouveau.

Смотрите также: [Ubuntu desktop hangs occasionally during regular use](https://askubuntu.com/q/874307/78223).